# Function not printing in the stdout

Tags: lua

Just to make it clear, it's my first time using the website as a member. I'm trying to make a code in Lua to read a file containing a morse encryption chart, read a file containing a message and then decrypt it and print it in the stdout. I've tried using the code above and debbug it, but have not had any success so far. The first function is working correctly, however, the loop in the two following functions seems to be for naught. As an observation: I've already done a similar code in C for a Data Structue assignment.

```
>

function lista()
    local table = {}
    io.input("morse.txt")
    local lines ={}
    for line in io.lines() do 
        lines[#lines+1] = line 
    end
    io.input(stdin)
    for i=1,#lines, 1 do
        local x; local y; local s;
        x, y = string.find(lines[i], " ")
        s=string.sub(lines[i], y+1, -1)
        local c=string.sub(lines[i], 1, 1)
        table[s]=c
        io.write(c, " ", s, "\n")
    end
    return table
end

function mensagem_cifrada()
    print("Mensagem cifrada")
    io.input("mensagem.txt")
    local words= {}
    local file = io.read("*all")
    for w in string.gmatch(file, "%a+") do
        print(#words)
        words[#words+1] = w
    end
    io.input(stdin)
    for i=1, (#words) do --Is not working
        print(i)
        io.write(i, words[i], " ")
    end
    io.write("\n")
    return words
end

function conversao(mensagem, table)
    print("Conversao")
    msg = {}
    for i=1, (#mensagem) do
        print(i)
        if mensagem[i] == "/" then
            msg[i] = " "
        else
            local s = mensagem[i]
            msg[i] = table[s]
        end
    end
    for i=1, #msg do -- Is not working
        print(i)
        io.write(i, msg[i])
    end
    io.write("\n")
    return msg
end

--Main Function

mensagem = {}
table = {}

table=lista()
mensagem=mensagem_cifrada()
conversao(mensagem, table)
```

--mensagem.txt

```
.--.. .-. .-.. .-. -.... .. -.. .... -.-.--. / ...-. ---. -.-.. .. .... / -.-.. ---. -.. .... .. --.. ..-. ... .-.. .-. --. / -... .. -.-.. ---. -... ... ..-.. ... -.-.. .-. .-.. / -.-.. ---. .-.. .-.. .. -. .-. --. .. -.. -. .. / .. .... -. .-. / --. .. -.. .... .-. --.. .. --. -.-.--. / .. -.. ...-. ... .. / .-. --.. ---. .-.. .-. / --. .. .... --. ---. / ..-. --. / .. -....-. --. .-. ... .-... / .--.. .-. .-.. .-. / .-. .-... -.-.. ..... ... .. .-.. ... .--.-.. -.-.. ... -.-.. .-.-.-. ..-. -.. -.... .-.-.-. -.... .-.. / .. / --. .-. .-.. --.-. ..-. .. / .-. / .-. .--.. .-.. .. .... .. -.. -. .-. -.-.. .-. ---. / -... ---. / -. .-.. .-. -.... .-. .-... ..... ---. -.-.--.
```

--morse.txt

```
A .-.
B -....
C -.-..
D -...
E ..
F ..-..
G --..
H .....
I ...
J .---.
K -.-.
L .-...
M --.
N -..
O ---.
P .--..
Q --.-.
R .-..
S ....
T -.
U ..-.
V ...-.
W .--.
X -..-.
Y -.--.
Z --...
1 .----.
2 ..---.
3 ...--.
4 ....-.
5 ......
6 -.....
7 --....
8 ---...
9 ----..
0 -----.
. .-.-.-.
, --..--.
? ..--...
' .----..
! -.-.--.
/ -..-..
( -.--..
) -.--.-.
& .-....
: ----....
; -.-.-..
= -...-.
- -....-.
_ ..--.-.
" .-..-..
$ ...-..-.
@ .--.-..
```

New piece of code

-

```
- Trabalho 2 de ED em Lua

function lista()
    local table = {}
    io.input("morse.txt")
    local lines ={}
    for line in io.lines() do 
        lines[#lines+1] = line 
    end
    io.input(stdin)
    for i=1,#lines, 1 do
        local x; local y; local s;
        x, y = string.find(lines[i], " ")
        s=string.sub(lines[i], y+1, -1)
        local c=string.sub(lines[i], 1, 1)
        table[s]=c
        io.write(c, " ", s, "\n")
    end
    return table
end

function mensagem_cifrada()
    print("Mensagem cifrada")
    io.input("mensagem.txt")
    local words= {}
    local file = io.read("*all")
    for w in string.gmatch(file, "[^%s]+") do
        words[#words+1] = w
    end
    io.input(stdin)
    for i, v in ipairs(words) do
        io.write(i, " ", v)
    end
    io.write("#words =", #words,"\n")
    io.write("\n")
    return words
end

function conversao(mensagem, tab)
    print("Conversao")
    msg = {}
    for i=1, (#mensagem) do
        if mensagem[i] == "/" then
            msg[i] = " "
        else
            local s = mensagem[i]
            msg[i] = tab[s]
        end
    end
    for i, v in ipairs(msg) do
        io.write(v)
    end
    io.write("\n")
    return msg
end

--Função Main

mensagem = {}
tab = {}

tab=lista()
mensagem=mensagem_cifrada()
conversao(mensagem, tab)
```

Expected output:

```
A .-.
B -....
C -.-..
D -...
E ..
F ..-..
G --..
H .....
I ...
J .---.
K -.-.
L .-...
M --.
N -..
O ---.
P .--..
Q --.-.
R .-..
S ....
T -.
U ..-.
V ...-.
W .--.
X -..-.
Y -.--.
Z --...
1 .----.
2 ..---.
3 ...--.
4 ....-.
5 ......
6 -.....
7 --....
8 ---...
9 ----..
0 -----.
. .-.-.-.
, --..--.
? ..--...
' .----..
! -.-.--.
/ -..-..
( -.--..
) -.--.-.
& .-....
: ----....
; -.-.-..
= -...-.
- -....-.
_ ..--.-.
" .-..-..
$ ...-..-.
@ .--.-..
Mensagem cifrada
1 .--..2 .-.3 .-..4 .-.5 -....6 ..7 -..8 ....9 -.-.--.10 /11 ...-.12 ---.13 -.-..14 ..15 ....16 /17 -.-..18 ---.19 -..20 ....21 ..22 --..23 ..-.24 ...25 .-..26 .-.27 --.28 /29 -...30 ..31 -.-..32 ---.33 -...34 ...35 ..-..36 ...37 -.-..38 .-.39 .-..40 /41 -.-..42 ---.43 .-..44 .-..45 ..46 -.47 .-.48 --.49 ..50 -..51 -.52 ..53 /54 ..55 ....56 -.57 .-.58 /59 --.60 ..61 -..62 ....63 .-.64 --..65 ..66 --.67 -.-.--.68 /69 ..70 -..71 ...-.72 ...73 ..74 /75 .-.76 --..77 ---.78 .-..79 .-.80 /81 --.82 ..83 ....84 --.85 ---.86 /87 ..-.88 --.89 /90 ..91 -....-.92 --.93 .-.94 ...95 .-...96 /97 .--..98 .-.99 .-..100 .-.101 /102 .-.103 .-...104 -.-..105 .....106 ...107 ..108 .-..109 ...110 .--.-..111 -.-..112 ...113 -.-..114 .-.-.-.115 ..-.116 -..117 -....118 .-.-.-.119 -....120 .-..121 /122 ..123 /124 --.125 .-.126 .-..127 --.-.128 ..-.129 ..130 /131 .-.132 /133 .-.134 .--..135 .-..136 ..137 ....138 ..139 -..140 -.141 .-.142 -.-..143 .-.144 ---.145 /146 -...147 ---.148 /149 -.150 .-..151 .-.152 -....153 .-.154 .-...155 .....156 ---.157 -.-.--.#words =157

Conversao
PARABENS! VOCES CONSEGUIRAM DECODIFICAR CORRETAMENTE ESTA MENSAGEM! ENVIE AGORA MESMO UM E-MAIL PARA ALCHIERI@CIC.UNB.BR E MARQUE A APRESENTACAO DO TRABALHO!
```

Comment: You've provided us a word wall with no hint as to where the problem is.

Comment: Which loop isn't working? Is any of this working the way you intended? What are the contents of `morse.txt`? What about `mensagem.txt`?

Comment: @EtanReisner. The following loops aren't working: **for i=1, (#words) do ** and **for i=1, #msg do **. The function lista() is working just as I intended. The morse.txt file contains in each line (%c %s), where c is a character and s a morse string associated with that character. The mensagem.txt file contains just on line with a sequence of alphabetic-morse strings separated by a space.

Comment: Do you see the `print(#words)` output (from `mensagem_cifrada`) when you run your code?

Comment: @EtanReisner. I do not see this output, though I see the output of print("Mensagem Cifrada")  which indicates the beginning of the function.

Comment: What do you see if you add `print(file)` before the `for w in ...` loop in `mensagem_cifrada`? Do you see the contents of the file you expect? Can you actually show us the contents of the two files?

Comment: @EtanReisner. I found the error. I was trying to match the file contents to a wrong pattern. The message is made of strings containing `"*", "-" and "/"` separated by spaces. So, I changed the pattern to `s tring.gmatch(file, "[^%s]+" `and the printed what I expected. However, I stiil have a doubt. Shouldn't' `string.gmatch(file, "[%-%*%/]+")` work just as well? I tried it but didn't get the expected output.

Comment: What output what do you get when you try that second pattern? It seems to work for me in a quick test. (But since you haven't actually supplied your input I can't test it on your input.)

Comment: @Etan. I edited the main topic including the input from the two files. The problem with the second pattern is that it seems to be reading only the "-" parts from message.txt.

Comment: The pattern `[%-%*%/]+` matches sequences of one or more `-`, `*` or `/` characters. Which doesn't include `.` which is part of your input. Did you mean `[%-%.%/]+`?

Comment: @EtanReisner. Yes, I meant `[%-%.%/]+`. I was careless. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Does that solve the problem? Are things working now?

Comment: @EtanReisner. It does solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell whether the problems are due to your code or due to your input. For instance, if "mensagem.txt" contains no letters, you'd see exactly the same result. However, there are some problems with your code that might explain what you're seeing.

First off: don't use 'table' as a variable name. 'table' is the name of the built-in module that contains methods for dealing with tables, such as table.length (for which '#' is syntactic sugar). If you overwrite the value of 'table', it's hard to predict what will go wrong, but you can reasonably expect anything to do with table manipulation to go wrong.

Second: table.length provides the number of contiguous numerically indexed entries in the table starting with entry '1'. I would avoid trying to do arithmetic on this for indexing: if you don't think things out just right, it's easy to lose most of your entries by skipping a slot. The table.insert function appends a value to the end of the table with the appropriate numeric key automatically. I didn't trace through to see if you were calculating it correctly, but I've been bitten by this enough times that I recommend never constructing a numeric index with arithmetic if you can avoid it.

Third: io.input is dangerous, since you're setting global state. I don't see evidence that it is causing the particular problem you're seeing right now, but you're better off using io.open to create a file object than literally changing the default stdin in individual functions based on the assumption that they will be called in a particular order, and handling this improperly can cause the kinds of errors you're seeing.

Here's a rewrite of the code with those particular problems fixed. See if it solves your problem. If it doesn't, inspect your data and then go over the code again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

function lista() 
    local tab = {}
    morseFile=io.open("morse.txt", "r")
    local lines ={}
    for line in morseFile:lines() do
        lines:insert(line)
    end
    for i=1,#lines, 1 do
        local x; local y; local s;
        x, y = string.find(lines[i], " ")
        s=string.sub(lines[i], y+1, -1)
        local c=string.sub(lines[i], 1, 1)
        table[s]=c  
        io.write(c, " ", s, "\n")
    end
    return tab
end

function mensagem_cifrada()
    print("Mensagem cifrada")
    local words= {}
    local msgFile = io.open("mensagem.txt", "r")
    for w in string.gmatch(msgFile.read("*all"), "%a+") do
        print(#words)  
        words:insert(w)
    end
    io.input(stdin)
    for i=1, (#words) do
        print(i)
        io.write(i, words[i], " ")
    end
    io.write("\n")
    return words
end

function conversao(mensagem, table)
    print("Conversao") 
    msg = {} 
    for i=1, (#mensagem) do
        print(i)
        if mensagem[i] == "/" then
            msg[i] = " "
        else  
            local s = mensagem[i]
            msg[i] = table[s]
        end
    end
    for i=1, #msg do
        print(i)
        io.write(i, msg[i])
    end
    io.write("\n")
    return msg
end

--Main Function

mensagem = {}
tab = {}

tab=lista()
mensagem=mensagem_cifrada()
conversao(mensagem, tab)
```

Comment: Thanks fot the feedback. I'm new to Lua programing. I'll try to incorporate your advice in future programs.I've described the text files in another comment. I've seen the chances you made. They generate the following message when I tried to run it: 'lua: morse.lua:6: attempt to call a nil value (method 'insert')
stack traceback:
 morse.lua:6: in function 'lista'
 morse.lua:61: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?
'

Comment: Technically table is a library, not a module. Modules are ```required```'d.

Comment: @warspyking All the built-in functionality are modules (or libraries) as well. You can `require("table")` just fine as well as inspect `package.loaded["table"]`. And non-default interpreters are not required to pre-load the `table` module the way the stock interpreter does.

Comment: @Etan That is true, I suppose, but it's still more commonly referred to as a library. Saying module COULD confuse people.

Comment: @warspyking That's true but it is a module and also a library and those are orthogonal labels. You can have a library that isn't a module and a module that isn't a library.

Comment: @Etan perhaps you should edit in how it's also a library. If I was new and had an answer like this I'd probably start ```require```'ing ```table```.

Comment: I said it was a built-in module. I feel like that's pretty unambiguous. Discussing the mechanics of how the default interpreter loads modules prior to parsing chunks is a distraction; my point was only that you're potentially overriding a builtin that controls how tables work.

Comment: The manual refers to it as a library in most places so that would be a slightly more appropriate term to have used but I don't know that it is a material difference in this answer. (So I'm certainly not going to edit it to change that but it would be reasonable for enkiv2 to do that if they chose to.)